# convert list to equation form

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list

```
condition={f'[t]-3,g'[t]-f[t]}
```

and now I want to use `DSolve` on it so I need to convert the list to

```
eqn={f'[t]-3==0,g'[t]-f[t]==0}
```

I can do that manually with this short list, but is there a way to do it programmatically with long lists by append `==0` to each item in the list?

Comment: `DSolve[Thread[condition == 0], {f[t], g[t]}, {t}]` will work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Thread[Equal[condition, 0]]
(*
 {-3+f′[t]==0,-f[t]+g′[t]==0}
*)
```